# how to create a transparent rectangle responding to click event in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to draw a rectangle in a tkinter.canvas to respond click event:

```
click_area = self.canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,pa_width,pa_height,fill='LightBlue',outline='lightBlue',tags=['A','CLICK_AREA'])
self.canvas.tag_bind('CLICK_AREA','<Button>',self.onClickArea)
```

it works.

at this moment, I have to draw a series of grid on the canvas, and I want them to be covered with the `click_area`, so that I need to make the `click_area` transparent.

but, when I wrote like this:

```
click_area = self.canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,pa_width,pa_height,fill='',outline='lightBlue',tags=['A','CLICK_AREA'])
```

it did **not** respond to click any longer.

So, my question is how to make it transparent and keep it responding to click. Or, is there any other way to implement what I want.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I got it: Bind the canvas, not the rectangle.

replace

```
self.canvas.tag_bind('CLICK_AREA','<Button>',self.onClickArea)
```

with

```
self.canvas.bind('<Button>',self.onClickArea)
```

problem solved.

Answer (score 4):

I came across this same issue trying to use the `find_closest` Canvas method to modify existing rectangles, but simply binding to the canvas didn't work. The issue is that a Tkinter rectangle without a fill will only respond to clicks on its border.

Then I read about the stipple argument to `create_rectangle` from [here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/create_rectangle.html):

> **stipple:**  A bitmap indicating how the interior of the rectangle will
>   be stippled.
>
> Default is stipple="", which means a solid color. A
>   typical value would be stipple='gray25'. Has no effect unless the fill
>   has been set to some color. [See Section 5.7, “Bitmaps”](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/bitmaps.html).

And the section on bitmaps states that only a few stipple options are available by default, but none of them are completely transparent. However, you ***can*** specify your own custom bitmap as an X bitmap image (a `.xbm` file).

XBM files are really just text files with a C-like syntax, so I made my own 2x2 bitmap with all transparent pixels and saved it as `transparent.xbm` in the same directory as my Tkinter script. Here's the code for the XBM file:

```
#define trans_width 2
#define trans_height 2
static unsigned char trans_bits[] = {
   0x00, 0x00
};
```

Then, you can specify the custom stipple by prefixing the `xbm` file name with a `@` when creating your rectangle:

```
self.canvas.create_rectangle(
    x1,
    y1,
    x2,
    y2,
    outline='green',
    fill='gray',  # still needed or stipple won't work
    stipple='@transparent.xbm',
    width=2
)
```

Note, you still need to provided some fill value or the stipple will not be applied. The actual fill value doesn't matter as the stipple will "override" it in the canvas.

Comment: thank you very much. I have been looking for a transparent fill solution for a while