# Python - Tkinter how to create transparent background responding to click events

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

I need to close my program when my transparent background is clicked but the problem is that TKinter do not register clicks on any transparent items unless something is beneath them like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39028661/12730071).

So if I do

```
from tkinter import *

firstTime = True

def backgroundClicked(event):
    if firstTime == False:
        print("clicked")
        quit()

window = Tk("Dynamic CheatSheet")
window.configure(bg="red")
window.attributes("-transparentcolor", "red")
window.geometry("500x500")

masterFrame = Frame(window, width=500, height=500, bg="red")
masterFrame.pack()
masterFrame.bind('<Button-1>', backgroundClicked)

firstTime = False

window.mainloop()
```

And then click the background it doesn't work, but if i make my background solid then the bindings work like a charm(try changing to e.g. "yellow").

Also `wm_attributes('-alpha', 0.0)` will not work for me because i want only part of the UI to be transparent.

I've also thought about using pynput to register every click, but I couldn't make it work simultaneously with tkinter.

So TLDR I want to make my transparent background register clicks in tkinter and I don't know how to do it.

I'm thankful for any response.

Comment: `listener = pynput.keyboard() ; listener.start() ; window.mainloop() ; listener.join()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to resolve problem with transparent color. Besides I use Linux which doesn't have this option.

But it shouldn't be problem to run pynput and tkinter - because `pynput` runs in separated thread.

```
listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release)
listener.start()

window.mainloop() 

linstener.join()
```

or

```
with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:

    window.mainloop() 

    listener.join()
```

Comment: Looks like it working now but i have one other question. When i use Destroy function inside on_click() my cursor will have visible input lag for few seconds.
I cannot see why would this happen. When using destroy function it will work just fine if it's outside pynput.

Comment: I don't know what can be the problem but I would add ie. `print(time.time)` between commands to see which command need more time to execute. Maybe problem is how you stop `listener`. Maybe you need also `listener.stop()`. Listener use `thread` which may need time to stop it.